# What Is this the correct way of Testing RESTFUL Web Service and How do I increase my code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

Below I have a REST API Im trying to test. I seem to have 69% Using the test class I have set up. Is this the correct way of testing my API and if so how do I increase the code coverage here. I read something about creating sample data within the test class itself and doing the test. I dont know if it applies here or not.

Here is my API

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/candidate/*')
global with sharing class RESTCandidateController {
    @HttpPost
    global static Id postCandidate() {  
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;  
        String jid = req.params.get('jid');
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;   
        String JSONBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        //Variables
        PCandidate c;
        Contact contact; Job__c job; Qualification__c qualification; Candidate__c candidate; 
        Job_Requisition__c jobRequisition;
        if (jid != null) {  
            JSONBody = JSONBody.replace('"currency"', '"currency_x"');
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(JSONBody);    
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {            
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    if (parser.getCurrentName() == null) {
                        c = (PCandidate)parser.readValueAs(PCandidate.class); 
                    }           
                }               
            }
            if (c != null) {
                contact = createContact(c);
                try {
                    candidate = new Candidate__c(
                        candidate__c = contact.Id,
                        Job_Requisition__c = [SELECT Id FROM Job_Requisition__c WHERE nid__c =: jid].Id
                    );
                    insert candidate;       
                } catch (DmlException e) {
                    for (Integer m = 0; m < e.getNumDml(); m ++) {
                        System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(m));
                    }
                }                           
            }
        }
        return contact.Id;
    }

    private static Contact createContact(PCandidate c) {
        Contact contact; Job__c job; Qualification__c qualification;
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldObjectMap = schema.SObjectType.Contact.Fields.getMap();
        List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldObjectMapValues = fieldObjectMap.values();
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                contact = new Contact();
                if (c.email != null) {contact.Email = c.email;}
                if (c.fName != null) {contact.FirstName = c.fName;}
                if (c.mName != null) {contact.MiddleName = c.mName;}
                if (c.lName != null) {contact.LastName = c.lName;} 
                if (c.maidenName != null) {contact.maidenName__c = c.maidenName;} 
                if (c.dob != null) {contact.Birthdate = c.getDob();} 
                if (c.gender != null) {contact.gender__c = c.gender;} 
                if (c.idNumber != null) {contact.idNumber__c = c.idNumber;} 
                if (c.passportNumber != null) {contact.passportNumber__c = c.passportNumber;} 
                if (c.race != null) {contact.race__c = c.race;} 
                if (c.nationality != null) {contact.nationality__c = c.nationality;} 
                if (c.about != null) {contact.about__c = c.about;} 
                if (c.interests != null) {contact.interests__c = c.interests;} 
                if (c.location != null) {contact.MailingStreet = c.location.street1 + ', ' + c.location.suburb; 
                    contact.MailingCity = c.location.city; 
                    contact.MailingState = c.location.province; 
                    contact.MailingPostalCode = c.location.postalCode; 
                    contact.MailingCountry = c.location.country;} 
                if (c.tel != null) {contact.Phone = c.tel;} 
                if (c.cell != null) {contact.MobilePhone = c.cell;} 
                if (c.careerObjectives != null) {contact.careerObjectives__c = c.careerObjectives;} 
                if (c.currentJob != null) {contact.currentEmployer__c = c.currentJob.employer; 
                    contact.currentPosition__c = c.currentJob.position;} 
                if (c.highestQualification != null) {contact.highestQualification__c = c.highestQualification;} 
                if (c.skills != null) {contact.skills__c = c.stringSkills();} 
                if (c.personality != null) {contact.personality__c = c.stringPersonality();} 
                if (c.languages != null) {contact.languages__c = c.stringLanguagesPicklist();} 
                if (c.seeking != null) {contact.seekingPositions__c = c.seeking.stringPositions(); 
                    contact.seekingType__c = c.seeking.type; 
                    contact.seekingSalaryCurrency__c = c.seeking.salary.currency_x; 
                    contact.seekingSalaryAmount__c = Decimal.valueOf(c.seeking.salary.amount); 
                    contact.seekingSalaryType__c = c.seeking.salary.type;} 
                if (c.relocation != null) {contact.relocation__c = Boolean.valueOf(c.relocation);} 
                if (c.social != null) {contact.facebook__c = c.social.facebook; 
                    contact.twitter__c = c.social.twitter; 
                    contact.linkedIn__c = c.social.linkedIn; 
                    contact.gtalk__c = c.social.gtalk; 
                    contact.skype__c = c.social.skype;} 
                if (c.homepage != null) {contact.homepage__c = c.homepage;} 
                if (c.blog != null) {contact.blog__c = c.blog;}
                if (c.disabled != null) {contact.disabled__c = Boolean.valueOf(c.disabled);} 
                if (c.source != null) {contact.source__c = c.source;}
                if (c.achievements != null) {contact.achievements__c = c.achievements;} 
                if (c.noticePeriod != null) {contact.noticePeriodNumber__c = c.noticePeriodNumber(); 
                    contact.noticePeriodType__c = c.noticePeriodPeriod();} 
                if (c.id != null) {contact.id__c = c.id;}   
                insert contact; 
                //Job History
                if (c.jobHistory != null) {
                    fieldObjectMap = schema.SObjectType.Job__c.Fields.getMap();
                    fieldObjectMapValues = fieldObjectMap.values();         
                    query = 'SELECT ';                      
                    for (Schema.SObjectField s : fieldObjectMapValues) {
                        String name = s.getDescribe().getName();
                        query += name + ', ';
                    }
                    query = query.subStringBeforeLast(',');
                    query += ' FROM Job__c WHERE contact__c = \'' + contact.Id + '\'';
                    List<Job__c> currentJobs = Database.query(query);
                    if (currentJobs.size() == 0) {                              
                        for (Integer i = 0; i < c.jobHistory.size(); i ++) {
                            try {
                                //Create new Job

                                job = new Job__c(
                                    contact__c = contact.Id,
                                    employer__c = c.jobHistory[i].employer,
                                    position__c = c.jobHistory[i].position,
                                    industry__c = c.jobHistory[i].industry,
                                    type__c = c.jobHistory[i].type,
                                    fromDate__c = c.jobHistory[i].getFromDate(),
                                    toDate__c = c.jobHistory[i].getToDate(),
                                    duties__c = c.jobHistory[i].duties,
                                    reasonForChange__c = c.jobHistory[i].reasonForChange
                                );
                                insert job; 
                            } catch (DmlException e) {
                                for (Integer j = 0; j < e.getNumDml(); j ++) {
                                    System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(j));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (Job__c currentJob : currentJobs) {
                            for (Integer k = 0; k < c.jobHistory.size(); k++) {
                                if (currentJob.employer__c.equals(c.jobHistory[k].employer) &&
                                    currentJob.position__c.equals(c.jobHistory[k].position) &&
                                    currentJob.industry__c.equals(c.jobHistory[k].industry) &&
                                    currentJob.type__c.equals(c.jobHistory[k].type) &&
                                    currentJob.fromDate__c.format().equals(c.jobHistory[k].getFromDate().format()) &&
                                    currentJob.toDate__c.format().equals(c.jobHistory[k].gettoDate().format()) &&
                                    currentJob.reasonForChange__c.equals(c.jobHistory[k].reasonForChange)
                                ) {
                                    c.jobHistory.remove(k);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (c.jobHistory.size() != 0) {
                            for (Integer l = 0; l < c.jobHistory.size(); l ++) {
                                try {
                                    //Create new Job
                                    job = new Job__c(
                                        contact__c = contact.Id,
                                        employer__c = c.jobHistory[l].employer,
                                        position__c = c.jobHistory[l].position,
                                        industry__c = c.jobHistory[l].industry,
                                        type__c = c.jobHistory[l].type,
                                        fromDate__c = c.jobHistory[l].getFromDate(),
                                        toDate__c = c.jobHistory[l].getToDate(),
                                        duties__c = c.jobHistory[l].duties,
                                        reasonForChange__c = c.jobHistory[l].reasonForChange
                                    );
                                    insert job; 
                                } catch (DmlException e) {
                                    for (Integer m = 0; m < e.getNumDml(); m ++) {
                                        System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(m));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    update contact;
                }
                //Qualifications
                if (c.qualifications != null) {                 
                    fieldObjectMap = schema.SObjectType.Qualification__c.Fields.getMap();
                    fieldObjectMapValues = fieldObjectMap.values();         
                    query = 'SELECT ';                      
                    for (Schema.SObjectField s : fieldObjectMapValues) {
                        String name = s.getDescribe().getName();
                        query += name + ', ';
                    }
                    query = query.subStringBeforeLast(',');
                    query += ' FROM Qualification__c WHERE contact__c = \'' + contact.Id + '\'';
                    List<Qualification__c> currentQualifications = Database.query(query);
                    if (currentQualifications.size() == 0) {
                        for (Integer i = 0; i < c.qualifications.size(); i++) {
                            try {
                                //Create new Qualification
                                qualification = new Qualification__c(
                                    contact__c = contact.Id, 
                                    institution__c = c.qualifications[i].institution,
                                    achievement__c = c.qualifications[i].achievement,
                                    degreeLevel__c = c.qualifications[i].degreeLevel,
                                    achieved__c = c.qualifications[i].getAchieved()
                                );
                                insert qualification;
                            } catch (DmlException e) {
                                for (Integer j = 0; j < e.getNumDml(); j ++) {
                                    System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(j));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (Qualification__c currentQualification : currentQualifications) {
                            for (Integer k = 0; k < c.qualifications.size(); k ++) {
                                if (currentQualification.institution__c.equals(c.qualifications[k].institution) &&
                                    currentQualification.achievement__c.equals(c.qualifications[k].achievement) &&
                                    currentQualification.degreeLevel__c.equals(c.qualifications[k].degreeLevel) &&
                                    currentQualification.achieved__c.format().equals(c.qualifications[k].getAchieved().format())
                                ) {
                                    c.qualifications.remove(k);
                                }                                       
                            }
                        }
                        if (c.qualifications.size() != 0) {
                            for (Integer l = 0; l < c.qualifications.size(); l ++) {
                                try {
                                    //Create new Qualification  
                                    qualification = new Qualification__c(
                                        contact__c = contact.Id,
                                        institution__c = c.qualifications[l].institution,
                                        achievement__c = c.qualifications[l].achievement,
                                        degreeLevel__c = c.qualifications[l].degreeLevel,
                                        achieved__c = c.qualifications[l].getAchieved()
                                    );  
                                    insert qualification;                                   
                                } catch (DmlException e) {
                                    for (Integer m = 0; m < e.getNumDml(); m ++) {
                                        System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(m));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    update contact;
                }           
            } catch (DmlException e) {
                for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i ++) {
                    System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(i));
                }
            }           
        }
        return contact;
    }
}
```

And here is my test class

```
@isTest
private class RESTCandidateControllerTest {
    static testMethod void testPostCandidate() {        
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        req.addParameter('jid', '00000');
        req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.requestURI = 'https://cs80.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/candidate';
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"email":"joe58@example.com","fName":"Jan","lName":"Doe","maidenName":"Dingle","dob":"30/12/1990","gender":"female","idNumber":"9012305006058","passportNumber":"9012305006058","race":"Black","nationality":"RSA","about":"Lorem ipsum..","interests":"Lorem ipsum..","location":{"street1":"99 Acme street","suburb":"Lonehill","city":"Johannesburg","province":"Gauteng","postalCode":"2129","country":"South Africa"},"tel":"+27123123412","cell":"+27123123412","careerObjectives":"Lorem ipsum","currentJob":{"employer":"Acme Inc.","position":"Senior bottle washer"},"jobHistory":[{"employer":"Example Inc.","position":"Junior receptionist","industry":"Construction","type":"Permanent","fromDate":"12/2010","toDate":"01/2014","reasonForChange":"Lorem ipsum"}],"highestQualification":"BSc IT","qualifications":[{"institution":"University of life","achievement":"BSc IT","degreeLevel":"Diploma","achieved":"2012"}],"skills":["HTML","Coocking"],"presonality":["Friendly","Hardworking"],"languages":["English","Afrikaans"],"seeking":{"positions":["Accountant","Web developer"],"type":"Permanent","salary":{"currency_x":"ZAR","amount":"10000","type":"annual"}},"relocation":true,"social":{"facebook":"username","twitter":"username","linkedIn":"username","gtalk":"username","skype":"username"},"homepage":"http://www.example.com/homepage","blog":"http://www.example.com/homepage","disabled":true,"source":"test system","achievements":"lorem ipsum","noticePeriod":"30 days"}');

        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;
        RESTCandidateController.postCandidate();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your REST class queries `Job__c` and `Qualification__c` and does different things depending on whether values are found. So your test class will need to have test cases where you insert matching `Job__c` and `Qualification__c` as well as where you do not insert matching values to cover both cases before the `postCandidate` method is called. This should increase the code coverage a bit.

I think you should have `currency` in your test request body string not `currency_x`.

Rather than a literal string in your tests to specify the JSON, you can use the same objects that the REST class created from the JSON to build the test requests and then use [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) to turn that data into the JSON string. This makes it easier to create variations of the data.

As well as calling the `postCandidate` method, your tests should assert that the method has done what you expect by querying for changes and using multiple calls to methods like [System.assertEquals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals).

It is not unusual for the tests class to be bigger than the class being tested because there may be many permutations of the inputs to check and many details to be checked in the results. To avoid unhelpful code duplication in the test class, you can use nested utility classes or helper methods shared by several test methods. You should look at the class you are testing and ensure that your tests cause most/all of the paths through the code to be taken. Achieving test coverage of about 90% is an indicator that you have pretty much done that.

In your REST class, this sort of error handling:

```
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i ++) {
                System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(i));
            }
        }
```

is just about never a good idea. A year from now no-one if going to be looking at the debug log but they are going to be wondering why the inserts and updates to the database are not handling. If the `DmlException`'s are an unexpected error condition, return a status such as HTTP 400 and some explanatory information (collected from the `DmlException`) as the return value. (You will have to change the return type from ID to String to do that; the ID can still be returned with the String return type. And the caller needs to know to check the HTTP status and took for the error information in the response body.)

Comment: Thank you Keith, however I dont think I can use the serialize option, because the json sent through to my org is not directly mappable to my objects, thats why I am hard coding the strings. So looking at my test class, how would I do the creations for Job__c and Qualifications__c etc to use in the test. If you could provide me a sample Id greatly appreciate it

Comment: @NelsonChisoko You will also have to first insert a Contact so you can set that Contact's ID in the `contact__c` field before you insert the Job__c and Qualifications__c. I suggest you Google and read up on Apex testing in genera; to get comfortable with how to do the data setup (and the assertions).

Comment: @NelsonChisoko - you may also find if you have a set of live JSON examples, that you can save these in static Resources and use them as mocked `requestBody`  - this is particularly helpful with complex JSON. See Keith'c remark about reading more on setting up test data